# cannot connect ssh between wifi and ethernet

Tags: ssh, wifi

i had connected my RPi to the router via Ethernet cable and had obtained an ip 192.168.1.1 
and my labtop connected to the router via wifi and obtained ip 192.168.1.104

so how can i connect RPi b+ to the labtop via ssh ????

is there any configuration need ?

Comment: It is unlikely that the IP is 192.168.1.1  Check `ifconfig` on the Pi (post output if you need help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Saleel said, 192.168.1.1 is most likely the IP for the router (it's an industry standard pretty much).

While your raspi is connected to the router, you can check your router's config page (head to 192.168.1.1 in your browser) and it should list the active clients connected and you'll see the LAN IP for all of them.

Then you'll SSH into you raspi with that IP.

Answer (score 0):

just use another ip than 192.168.1.1 for the RPi 
because that one is the default of the router

Answer (score 0):

Personally, my router (box) has the ip 192.168.1.254, so it might be possible to get 192.168.1.1 for a device.

To check the ip address on your Raspberry type

```
hostname -I
```

to connect from another computer to the pi:

**On a MAC**, type

```
ssh USER@IP.ADDRESS
```

so it may look like :

```
ssh pi@192.168.1.1
```

**On a PC**, use putty, link is http://www.putty.org/